# Duplicate fields/values from JSON object array in php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am working on a website in which I want to remove duplicate fields from JSON object array.

The JSON object array which I have is:

```
"rental_rates": [{
    "rate_id": 170,
    "uuid": "a3a14d20-63d1-11e8-b047-89e5d3a9513d",
    "owner_id": 38,
    "item_id": 394,
    "name": "daily",
    "term": "daily",
    "currency": "dollars",
    "rate": "56.00",
    "min_charge": "56.00",
    "created_at": "2018-05-30 06:20:43",
    "updated_at": "2018-05-30 06:21:07"
}, {
    "rate_id": 172,
    "uuid": "a3a1c500-63d1-11e8-8740-8925bbb8ada8",
    "owner_id": 38,
    "item_id": 394,
    "name": "weekly",
    "term": "weekly",
    "currency": "dollars",
    "rate": "677.00",
    "min_charge": "56.00",
    "created_at": "2018-05-30 06:21:00",
    "updated_at": "2018-05-30 06:21:07"
}],
```

The code which I am using in order to pull fields/values form JSON object array is:

```
foreach ($data['item']->rental_rates as $rental_rate)
{
echo '<span class="rental_term" style="text-align:right">'."minimum".'</span>';
echo '<span class="rental_price" style="text-align:right">$'.floatval($rental_rate->min_charge).'</span><br>';

}
```

The above code is pulling the following data and I want only one to be shown.

```
minimum $56
minimum $56
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I need to make in the foreach loop so it pull only one field and value like this,

```
minimum $56
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways. Store what has already been displayed and check for it:

```
$shown = array();
foreach ($data['item']->rental_rates as $rental_rate)
{
    if(!in_array($rental_rate->min_charge, $shown)) {
        $shown[] = $rental_rate->min_charge;
        echo '<span class="rental_term" style="text-align:right">'."minimum".'</span>';
        echo '<span class="rental_price" style="text-align:right">$'.floatval($rental_rate->min_charge).'</span><br>';
    }
}
```

Or create an array indexed by the `min_value` so there will only ever be one (only works on objects as of PHP >= 7.0.0):

```
$rates = array_column($data['item']->rental_rates, null, 'min_charge');
foreach $rates as $rental_rate)
{
    echo '<span class="rental_term" style="text-align:right">'."minimum".'</span>';
    echo '<span class="rental_price" style="text-align:right">$'.floatval($rental_rate->min_charge).'</span><br>';
}
```

For PHP < 7.0.0, decode the JSON as an array passing `true` as the second argument and use `$data['item']['rental_rates']` and `$rental_rate['min_charge']` in the code above instead.